# Signed Android APK from TFS build server intermittently crashing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

> Environment info: App developed in C#/Xamarin/VS2015. CI build in TFS
>   build server produces signed APK using keystore specified in .csproj
>   file. Xamarin version 4.3.0.789 and Xamarin.Android version 7.1.0.43.

Problem I am having is that every now and then, for no apparent reason, the APK produced will crash on opening a certain screen/activity. When it is a "faulty" APK it will always happen on the same screen. There are no code changes between a valid and faulty APK (have verified by changing comments in unrelated file to kick off CI build), and no changes to the TFS server/environment.

Nothing different occuring on device between APKs, and verified this across multiple devices. Was on older versions of Xamarin with same issue, have tried updating and continue to get same issue.

Running locally in debug it is impossible to repro. Shared Runtime is disabled, linker is set to SDK assemblies only. No errors in the builds that produce faulty APK.

The logcat message pasted below references SimpleListItem2CheckedIndexedAdapter which is a custom checkable view used in a few places. But since APK works fine most times I'm wondering if this is a red herring.

```
--------- beginning of system
04-03 15:19:39.894 I/ActivityManager( 1092): START u0 {cmp=PackageName/md5ba12c8fb46bd054e4b4e431f91f82328.VehicleCheckView (has extras)} from uid 10194 on display 0
04-03 15:19:40.039 W/art     (11339): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md5ac3c6372e65750ca70261904a169a5a9.VehicleCheckFragmentPage
04-03 15:19:40.151 I/MonoDroid(11339): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339): System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException (System.ExceptionResource resource) [0x0000b] in <7c63250b2e0e4a7ea8b6c66479c70025>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Insert (TKey key, TValue value, System.Boolean add) [0x0008e] in <7c63250b2e0e4a7ea8b6c66479c70025>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key, TValue value) [0x00000] in <7c63250b2e0e4a7ea8b6c66479c70025>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Java.Interop.TypeManager.RegisterType (System.String java_class, System.Type t) [0x00041] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Android.Runtime.TypeManager.RegisterType (System.String java_class, System.Type t) [0x00000] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.RegisterJniNatives (System.IntPtr typeName_ptr, System.Int32 typeName_len, System.IntPtr jniClass, System.IntPtr methods_ptr, System.Int32 methods_len) [0x000de] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods:java_interop_jnienv_call_object_method_a (intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*)
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006b] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002f] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x0005e] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Namespace.SimpleListItem2CheckedIndexedAdapter.GetView (System.Int32 position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent) [0x00015] in <a29411822a8f4191a468d308d15ef1cd>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 position, System.IntPtr native_convertView, System.IntPtr native_parent) [0x0001a] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0 
04-03 15:19:40.154 I/MonoDroid(11339):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:b093adad-cfc1-48f4-a34a-b2217060ac97 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr)
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339): Stacktrace:
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339): 
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_find_class (intptr,intptr&,string) <0x00007>
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment/Types.FindClass (string) [0x00039] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (string) [0x00007] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type) [0x0006a] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type) [0x0003a] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (string,System.Type,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x00042] in <013bf3b17eee4306bb0bc5e86d09290c>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Lang.Throwable..ctor (string) [0x00055] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Android.Runtime.JavaProxyThrowable..ctor (System.Exception) [0x00007] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Java.Lang.Throwable.FromException (System.Exception) [0x00023] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledException (System.Exception) [0x0007e] in <255c4ce2d8d0441c8d86df754d96e9d9>:0
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.b093adad-cfc1-48f4-a34a-b2217060ac97 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr) <0x00057>
04-03 15:19:40.159 E/mono-rt (11339):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.b093adad-cfc1-48f4-a34a-b2217060ac97 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr) <0x0008f>
04-03 15:19:40.160 E/mono-rt (11339): /proc/self/maps:
```

Comment: Do you have an `Android.App.Application` subclass defined in your app? And which `Xamarin.Android` version are you using?

Comment: When I was doing Xamarin development a year or so ago, this would happen to me all the time.  Just randomly, a debug build would crash on my test device.  I just got in the habit of running it twice to make sure crashes were legit...

Comment: @SushiHangover Yeah, MainApp inherits from Android.App.Application and overrides OnCreate to get past known issue. Using Xmarain 4.3.0.789 and Xamarin.Android 7.1.0.43. Updated to latest to try fix it, but has happened on old and new versions.

Comment: @MrZander Unfortunately when it starts producing faulty APKs it keeps producing them, and I lose a day changing project settings until it magically works again, only to happen again a few days later (sadface)

Comment: @KrustyGString Ouch, Xamarin has it's kinks, hope you find a solution.  Also, your username is hilariously disgusting.